# "ord() expected a character, but string of length 15..."

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to know how many times each letter appears in a sentence. However, it gives an error "ord () expected a character, but string of length 15" (15 and the amount of letters contained in my current file)

```
texto = open('teste.txt','r')
ocorrencias = [0] * 25 

ord_a = ord("a")

for caracter in texto:
    if caracter >= 'a' and caracter <= 'z':
        ocorrencias[ord(caracter) - ord_a] += 1
```

Comment: you are trying to ord a word, add another for-loop. ( print caracter to debug)

Comment: File iterators yield *lines*, not individual characters/bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
texto = open('teste.txt','r')
ocorrencias = [0] * 26

ord_a = ord("a")

for caracter in texto:
    for c in caracter:
        if c >= 'a' and c <= 'z':
            ocorrencias[ord(c) - ord_a] += 1
print(ocorrencias)
texto.close()
```

Comment: Check now, I have updated the size of the list-occuencias.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools` to adapt your code with one small change. A file iterator produces *lines* of text, and you want each *character* within a line.

The `chain` class is used to create a new iterable by chaining together multiple iterables; it yields the items from one iterable, then items from the next, until all the original iterables are exhausted.

Since `texto` itself is iterable (yielding `str` objects), you can chain those values
together into one long "virtual" `str` which yields the individual characters you want.

```
from itertools import chain

texto = open('teste.txt','r')
ocorrencias = [0] * 26  # You still need 26 slots, even if they are indexed 0 to 25

ord_a = ord("a")

for caracter in chain.from_iterable(texto):
    if caracter >= 'a' and caracter <= 'z':
        ocorrencias[ord(caracter) - ord_a] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using an additional loop over the words

```
texto = open('teste.txt','r')
ocorrencias = [0] * 26 

ord_a = ord("a")

for words in texto:
    for character in words:
        if character >= 'a' and character <= 'z':
            ocorrencias[ord(character) - ord_a] += 1
```